# Rendering lines with more than 256 points on a canvas in Safari for Ipad

Tags: google-chrome, ipad, canvas, safari, html5-canvas

There appears to be a bug with canvas in both chrome and Safari for Ipad.

If I render a single line with 256 points the line renders as expected.

If I render a single line with more than 256 points the line is broken into two or more separate lines.

The following JS fiddle shows two lines, the top line has 256 points, the bottom line has 257 points. They are otherwise identical.

The bottom one consistently renders in 3 parts on ipad. I'd be interested to see what causes this, and what possible solutions there are

https://jsfiddle.net/g26t8adL/2/

[image: Two lines rendered in safari for ipad]

```js
(function() {
  // prep canvas
  let canvas = document.getElementById('c')
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  canvas.width = 700
  canvas.height = 300
  
  // prep stroke
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5
  ctx.lineWidth = 30
  ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round'
  
  // draw 256 point on canvas
  ctx.beginPath()
  for(let i=0; i< 256; i++){
    ctx.lineTo((50+(i*2)), 100)
  }
  ctx.stroke()
  
  // draw 257 point on canvas
  ctx.beginPath()
  for(let i=0; i< 257; i++){
    ctx.lineTo((50+(i*2)), 200)
  }
  ctx.stroke()
})();
```

```css
body{
  background: #ccc;
}

canvas{
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Can repro on Safari for macOs. This is worth a [bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/). Since you are setting both lineJoin and lineCap to round, I think (though not entirely sure) that you could just add a `moveTo(x, y)` call right after the `lineTo(x,y)` one. It seems to work for me so far. An other way for the exposed case would be to draw the path will full opacity and then redraw it with transparency, but this wouldn't help with e.g line-dashes, which are also affected by that bug...